# jQuery email field validation some problem

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I want to apply some conditions to the email address of the form field. The email address field is optional. The condition is-

1. Do not show any errors when the email field is empty.
2. But the error will only show when there is a value in the email field + the mail format does not match.

I did it well with the following jQuery code. But here's the problem - when I apply this condition **[ !$("#billing_email").val().match(/^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i ) ]**, even if the email field is empty, the mail address is still required! But the mail field is not required.

How do I solve this problem?

```js
$('form.checkout').on('submit', function () {
if ( $("#billing_email").val()!== '' && !$("#billing_email").val().match(/^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i )) {

  if ( $("#billing_email").parent().next(".error").val() !== '') {
    $("#billing_email").parent().after("<span class='error'>Invalid email...</span>");
    $("#billing_email").focus(); //Focus on field   
  }
} 

else {
  $("#billing_email").parent().next(".error").remove();
} 
});
```

Comment: Have you checked email field does not contain any space ?  If it contain any space then trim value before checking condition.

Comment: explain please....

Comment: `"    "== "" ` this condition will evaluate to false in js as first string contains space . Now  `$("#billing_email").val()` will have any space then `$("#billing_email").val() != ""` will return true and second condition will be checked which may be false . So try condition like  `$("#billing_email").val().trim() !== ''`

Comment: Not wok properly...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just works fine. I think you might need to add:

```
$(this).find('.error').remove();
```

before the `if` condition.

Comment: Yes, the code is working well. But when the email field is empty, it is not submitted until the email is given there. But the email field is optional. Removing this line "!$("#billing_email").val().match(/^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i ) ]," again is submitted, but the error message is not displayed properly! Any ideas ..?

Comment: Check if there's an attribute named `required` exists in the Element. If it is, you have to remove that attribute to pass the Browser validation.

Comment: Email address field is optional. Not required

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there's no problem with the front-end code. You are using woocommerce right? and you need the `billing email address` as optional. You need to set the `billing email` not required using `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook in `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_checkout_fields' );

function override_checkout_fields($fields) {
  $fields['billing']['billing_email']['required'] = false;
  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using woocommerce. With this filter I have already made the Required field optional. I want the form to be submitted when there is no value in the field. The error is also displayed properly.

Comment: Could you provide link to your website or the screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working as intended. I just tweaked it a bit to be more readable and to have more ' specific ' conditions.

Check below

( i changed from submit to click so i can test it without submitting, you can change it back to submit )

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  const emailInput = $("#billing_email")
  const emailInputVal = $(emailInput).val()
  const emailInputParent = $(emailInput).parent()
  if (
    $(emailInputVal).trim().length > 0 &&
    !$(emailInputVal).match(/^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i)
  ) {

    if ($(emailInputParent).next(".error").length === 0) {
      $(emailInputParent).after("<span class='error'>Invalid email...</span>");
      emailInput.focus(); //Focus on field   
    }
  } else {
    $(emailInputParent).next(".error").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkout">
  <span>
    <input id="billing_email" type="text">
  </span>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```