# JQuery keyup function - error/div show/hide some problem

Tags: html, jquery, css

jQuery keyup function works. But there is a problem here. When I give data/value in one field, errors in other fields are also hidden. But I want to show / hide only that field when I give value or data.

```js
$('#trexright input').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
    $('.field_error').hide();
  } else {
    $('.field_error').show();
  }     
});
```

```css
#trexright p,
.form_field input {
  width: 100%;
}

#trexright span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="trexright">
<p class="form-row">
  <label for="first_name" class="">First Name</label>
  <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="first_name_class" name="first_name" id="first_name_id" placeholder="First name" value="">
  </span>
  <span class="field_error">This field is required.</span>
</p>

<p class="form-row">
  <label for="last_name" class="">Last Name</label>
  <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="last_name_class" name="last_name" id="last_name_id" placeholder="Last name" value="">
  </span>
  <span class="field_error">This field is required.</span>
</p>

<p class="form-row">
  <label for="location" class="">Location</label>
  <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="location_class" name="location" id="location_id" placeholder="Location" value="">
  </span>
  <span class="field_error">This field is required.</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are hiding/showing all the `.field-error` elements.

You need to make a ' connection ' between `$(this)` which is the changed input and it's corresponding `field-error`

With the current HTML structure you can use the [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method to select the `field-error` that comes after the input

EDIT: after OP changed HTML structure.

Now the field-error is not a sibling for input so you cannot use `next`. But instead select the parent of the input ( span ) and then use next to select the field-error.

I also formatted a bit the code so it's more concise.

NOTE. As a personal advice. Please start learning the jquery methods. And see how you can traverse the HTML structure in order to select the items you want. Another advice is to start learning plain javascript and avoid using jquery altogether especially for large projects.

```js
$('#trexright input').keyup(function() {
  const inputError = $(this).parent('span').next('.field_error');
  $(this).val().length > 0 ? $(inputError).hide() : $(inputError).show()
 
});
```

```css
#trexright{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trexright">
<p class="form-row">
  <label for="first_name" class="">First Name</label>
  <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="first_name_class" name="first_name" id="first_name_id" placeholder="First name" value="">
  </span>
  <span class="field_error">This field is required.</span>
</p>

<p class="form-row">
  <label for="last_name" class="">Last Name</label>
  <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="last_name_class" name="last_name" id="last_name_id" placeholder="Last name" value="">
  </span>
  <span class="field_error">This field is required.</span>
</p>

<p class="form-row">
  <label for="location" class="">Location</label>
  <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="location_class" name="location" id="location_id" placeholder="Location" value="">
  </span>
  <span class="field_error">This field is required.</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The code is working. Butt I gave the wrong HTML input. Now I have updated the code. Would you please give me a solution to this update code? I am accepting your answer.

Comment: @MaryXNabors edited the answer to work for your updated HTML structure

Comment: The code is not working on my ecommerce checkout page! why ??

Comment: @MaryXNabors well, if it works in the snippet it should work on your page. Maybe the HTML structure is not the one you shared. I cannot tell you why :)

Comment: All right. Problem solved. I fixed it. Thank you again. 
I am facing a few more problems in this regard. I have posted about this in stackoverflow.. But did not get a response. Please help me? Shall I share the link here? There will be many benefits.

Comment: Yes. Ofc. share the link. ' many benefits ' ? :)) I am sure there will be :) for you. Hopefully the benefits are that you learn something about jquery methods. Don't just rely on stackoverflow to make your website

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333203/jquery-email-field-validation-some-problem/68334021?noredirect=1#comment120770286_68334021

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325126/jquery-each-empty-required-field-focus-scroll-top

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324437/woocommerce-add-to-cart-redirect

Answer (score -1):

Try this will be work fine.

```
$('#trexright input').keyup(function() {

  if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
    $('input:focus').next('.field_error').hide();
  } else {
    $('input:focus').next('.field_error').show();
  }     
})
```

Comment: why use nextAll and then :first pseudo selector ? and not use next ? which selects the ' closest ' next sibling ? also, `:first` is deprecated https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/